# does GPU cuda code works on multiple GPU cards without needs of any implementation?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I have already a GPU CUDA C++ based code which works well on a single NVIDIA Graphic card. Is it possible to speedup the calculation by adding a new NVIDIA card and run the code on 2 GPU cards (the old one and the new one)? 
I mean do I need to write any new code for make the current code ready for running on two GPU cards or it works without any new implementation?

Comment: It is required to modify your code to support N cards - split your work in N parts and send each to a separate GPU.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't. Most device control code like kernel launching, cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy are targeting one specific device, you need to use cudaSetDevice to specify the device you want to execute, something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < gpuCount; i++)

{
    cudaSetDevice(i);

    cudaMemcpy(...)

    some_kernel_func<<...>>> (...)        

}
```